# How to make npx run the js cli script in windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npx

**The Problem -** My `npx` scaffolding script works fine on linux but doesn't work on windows. However I see a lot packages which runs fine on windows but I couldn't find out what they are doing differently. I asked AI tools (Chatgpt/Gemini) they couldn't provide a solution.

**What happens on linux?** - Script is normally executed by node and works fine.
**What happens on windows?** - It just opens a new command prompt window doing nothing.

- I created a npm package `@reuk/start` for scaffolding my commonly used project templates.
- I intented to use it as npx script. similar to `npx create-vite`.
- For this i created a script and added that to the bin field in my `package.json` -> `"bin": "./bin/cli.js"`. and published the package.
- Running the script normally like `node ./bin/cli.js` works perfectly fine. the only problem is when doing `npx @reuk/start` it is not invoking the script using node.
- My `cli.js` has a shebang `#!/usr/bin/env node` to tell the interpreter to run it using node. I know shebang only works in unix systems and windows doesn't support it, but how does create-vite work on windows, and why doesn't mine work despite having the similar code?

What am I doing wrong here? And more importantly how do I make it work cross platform seamlessly?

For reference here is the code -
[@reuk/start](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@reuk/start?activeTab=code) | [create-vite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-vite?activeTab=code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the name of your `bin` script clashes with a [cmd start command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Start_(command)).

The fix could be choosing a more specific name for the command under which you want your script to be available. This name should also be a valid filename to avoid any further issues.

In package.json:

```json
"bin": {
  "rvg": "bin/cli.js"
}
```

---

Here is a simplified and technically imprecise explanation of what is going on when you run `npx @reuk/start`:

1. npx tries to resolve the package using the usual node.js package resolution mechanism
2. if nothing is found it installs the package globally
3. npm sees the `bin` section in `package.json` and creates platform-specific wrappers under `node_modules/.bin` folder. In your case, it adds files named `start` because another command - @reuk/start is not a valid file name.
4. npx tries to run `start` but it resolves to cmd command and not your script.

To be honest, the last point seems to be a bug, and there are pretty many open bugs related to scoped packages in general, but I have not find any explaining this particular case.

Comment: Perfect! That worked. The name of script being `start` was the issue which conflicted with `cmd` `start` command. Changing it to anything else fixed the issue. Although I am not sure why doing `"bin": "./bin/cli.js"` didn't work, is it also because the name of the scoped package is also `start` or because `@reuk/start` is not a valid file name and npx failed to create any script in `.bin` for this package, so creating a named script was essential?

Comment: @RohitKaushal yes, I guess so. Also, it may be some issue similar to [this one](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2894). Anyway, even if you put a name as I suggested, npx should correctly work with the full package name `npx @reuk/start`.